Error Connecting NodeMCU ESP 8266 to an eclipse mqtt server running on windows 11 over SSL/TLS
I have set up the .conf file with all the necceassy config like this -
listener 8883
protocol mqtt
certfile path/to/server.crt {yes the actual path i just removed it from here}
keyfile path/to/server.key
require_certificate true
cafile path/to/ca.crt
log_type all
allow_anonymous false

and also have uploaded the ca.crt, client.key and client.crt to the esp's files system
Now when I run the mosquitto -v -c "path/to/mosquitto.conf"
it shows -
1731107545: mosquitto version 2.0.20 starting
1731107545: Config loaded from path/to/mosquitto.conf.
1731107545: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1731107545: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1731107545: mosquitto version 2.0.20 running
1731107547: New connection from 192.168.66.1:58821 on port 8883.
1731107552: Client <unknown> disconnected: protocol error.

and the serail monitor for my esp shows -
Connected to WiFi
CA certificate loaded
Client certificate loaded
Client private key loaded
Attempting MQTT connection...Failed to connect, rc=-2

Here is the esp Client code -
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <LittleFS.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// WiFi credentials
const char* ssid = "ANSHUL_SOHAL";
const char* password = "12345678";

// MQTT server details
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.66.176";
const int mqtt_port = 8883;  // SSL port

WiFiClientSecure espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    // Connect to WiFi
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
    }
    Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

    // Mount LittleFS to access certificate files
    if (!LittleFS.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to mount LittleFS");
        return;
    }

    // Load CA certificate
    File ca = LittleFS.open("/ca.crt", "r");
    if (ca) {
        if (espClient.loadCACert(ca)) {
            Serial.println("CA certificate loaded");
        } else {
            Serial.println("Failed to load CA certificate");
        }
        ca.close();
    } else {
        Serial.println("CA certificate file not found");
    }

    // Load Client certificate
    File clientCert = LittleFS.open("/client.crt", "r");
    if (clientCert) {
        if (espClient.loadCertificate(clientCert)) {
            Serial.println("Client certificate loaded");
        } else {
            Serial.println("Failed to load client certificate");
        }
        clientCert.close();
    } else {
        Serial.println("Client certificate file not found");
    }

    // Load Client private key
    File clientKey = LittleFS.open("/client.key", "r");
    if (clientKey) {
        if (espClient.loadPrivateKey(clientKey)) {
            Serial.println("Client private key loaded");
        } else {
            Serial.println("Failed to load client private key");
        }
        clientKey.close();
    } else {
        Serial.println("Client private key file not found");
    }

    // Configure MQTT server
    client.setServer(mqtt_server, mqtt_port);
}

void reconnect() {
    // Attempt to connect to MQTT server
    while (!client.connected()) {
        Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
        if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {  // Unique Client ID
            Serial.println("Connected to MQTT server securely");
        } else {
            Serial.print("Failed to connect, rc=");
            Serial.println(client.state());
            delay(5000);  // Retry every 5 seconds
        }
    }
}

void loop() {
    if (!client.connected()) {
        reconnect();
    }
    client.loop();
}

can anyone please advice and help
I tried without SSL and it works I even tired running
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8883 -CAfile path\to\ca.crt -cert path\to\client.crt -key path\to\client.key
and it also works and connects succefully without errors.

Are you also providing a username in the client code? if not add use_identity_as_username true to the mosquitto.conf to use the client cert cn as the username (since you have allow_anonymous false). The openssl command is only opening a TCP connection, not sending a MQTT Connect packet.

It would probably help to include the client code in the question as well (use the Edit option)

I added the esp client code to the question. And also tried the solution that @hardillb provided with 'use_identity_as_username true' but it didn't worked same error

mqtt_server = "192.168.66.176"; If this is the server that the client wants to connect over TLS, you probably get a name mismatch certificate error. FQDN that matches the MQTT server's TLS certificate's CN, or one of SAN (subject alternate name if exists) DNS names should be used to connect to the server. You may check CAPI2 logs and SChannel logs (under System) on the client Event Viewer logs.
